# Casperjs click and ajax

Tags: ajax, click, casperjs

I'm trying to use casperjs on easyjet.com  because it is very similar to what I have to test in the future, (very similar ajax part in result page).

In the flight results page when I click on a link I can not trigger any action ajax.

From debugging I see that the link is then clicked but does not trigger ajax part.

I cannot understand where I'm wrong.

Thanks in advance

this is the code:

```
casper.thenEvaluate (function () {
    casper.waitForSelector ("# Flight3987022. priceSmaller.targetPrice.formatedPrice.cellPrice", 
        function success () {
            casper.assertExists ("# Flight3987022. priceSmaller.targetPrice.formatedPrice.cellPrice"); 
            this.click ("# Flight3987022. priceSmaller.targetPrice.formatedPrice.cellPrice"); 
        }, 
        function fail () {
           casper.assertExists ("# Flight3987022. priceSmaller.targetPrice.formatedPrice.cellPrice"); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I guess it is a typo, but you shouldn't have space between "#" and "Flight3987022", and no space between "." and "priceSmaller", but you do need spaces before each of the other periods.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `thenEvaluate()` outer function, and call `casper.waitForSelector()` directly.

`thenEvaluate()` is used for running JavaScript inside the web page. The `casper` object isn't available in that scope.